# ReactToastify.css.map not found (Next 13 /app folder)

Tags: javascript, next.js13, react-toastify

When trying to import the css from the React-tostify lib `import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css'` I get the following error:

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:3000/_next/static/css/app/ReactToastify.css.map`

I've already tried deleting my node_modules, .next, I'm on the latest version of Next (13.4.19) and React-toastify (9.1.3). I've tried every possible solution but nothing has worked.

The strange thing is that Toast components work normally for me, as do their styles, whether running Next in development or production. The only error is this message that appears in the console.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Next.js14 (App Router) and had the same problem.

When I moved `import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css'` from layout.tsx to the global CSS file, the warning disappeared.

```
@import '~react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.min.css';
```

Comment: I've been using the Sonner library since then, it's much more popular and stable! She is in all my projects with next.